# AccessControlException while connecting MySQL using JDBC in GWT hosted mode

Tags: gwt, mode, hosted, accesscontrolexception

I want to connect to a mysql database at localhost:3306 using jdbc in a GWT servlet, but when I try connecting I get this error:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)
...
```

I know that I need to apply a security policy for tomcat to solve this problem, something like this:

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/webapps/-" {
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "192.168.12.81:3306", "connect";
};
```

But I don't know where should I apply this change? Please provide a solution for both hosted & web mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are not using the **Google App Engine** (I'm assuming here you are using the **Google Eclipse Plugin**): go to your project's properties -> **Google** -> **App Engine**, and make sure it's unchecked.

If this doesn't help, read through the suggestions in [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/google-web-toolkit@googlegroups.com/msg14413.html).